# How to merge record data and a pdf attachment and generate a single pdf in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, merge

I have one pdf file as an attachment of record. I want to create a single pdf file that contains some data from the record as the first page and the attached pdf file as the next page. How I can achieve this in apex?

Comment: Unless you can get the underlying HTML for each and then merge into a single PDF I think you're out of luck, unless there's a 3rd party service you can use to merge PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in apex. You may look for third party API like [this](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge)